# Bulk Record Issue : Missing value for required field(s) in batch class

Tags: batch

Problem facing :  Missing value for required field(s): OrderFields:

> Debug Log details

> ordPrd.orderId*******null@@@@@@prdId@@@@@a0c3H000000SOp7QAG

> ord **********OrderItem:{ExternalId__c=24203223, Quantity=1}

> ordPrd.orderId*******8013H000000Ec7rQAC@@@@@@prdId@@@@@a0c3H000000SOp6QAG
> ord **********OrderItem:{ExternalId__c=24187329, Quantity=24, UnitPrice=407.0,

> OrderId=8013H000000Ec7rQAC, PricebookEntryId=01u3H000001kceQQAQ, ListPrice=1.00}

> 04:38:53.0 (42477166)|USER_DEBUG|[197]|DEBUG|createProductList@@@@(OrderItem:{ExternalId__c=24187329, Quantity=24, UnitPrice=407.0, OrderId=8013H000000Ec7rQAC, PricebookEntryId=01u3H000001kceQQAQ, ListPrice=1.00, Product2Id=01t3H000000PVTmQAO}, OrderItem:{ExternalId__c=24203223, Quantity=1, Product2Id=01t3H000000PVTmQAO})

---

I had taken the first record from createprodctlist and tried to insert through anonymous window its working fine.

```
 OrderItem  ord1 =new OrderItem();
 ord1.Quantity=24;
  ord1.UnitPrice=407.0;
 ord1.OrderId='8013H000000Ec7rQAC';
 ord1.PricebookEntryId='01u3H000001kceQQAQ';
 insert ord1;
```

[Not used product 2Id  while inserting orderItem, Not a require field ]  Record has been created successfully.

Question purpose Showing only 2 records

**but in batch 1 records has to fail other one has to create**
**Expectation : 1 records has to fail (because required fields are missing), one records has to be processed**

complete code

```
 global class CT1_BatchOrderLineUpdate  implements Database.Batchable<sObject>  {
 public static final string ORDERINTEGRATION_SUCESSSTATUS ='Success';
public static final string ORDERINTEGRATION_JOBSTATUS ='Processed';
public static final string  ORDERINTEGRATION_CREATED ='Order Record has been 
 created Successfully';
public static final string  ORDERINTEGRATION_ERROR ='Order Record has an 
 Error';
public static final string ORDERINTEGRATION_ERRORSTATUS ='Error';
 //START Method
  global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
  //Querying order Product Integration Table starts
  // removed from code : for reducing code
  //It passes 2 records to scope
 //end
  }
 global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, 
List<Order_Product_Integration__c> scope) {
//Variable Declaration block
List<orderItem> createProductList = new List<orderItem>();
Set<String> orderAndLines = new Set<String>();
Set<String> orderProduct = new Set<String>();
List<Order_Product_Integration__c> updateOrderIntegration = new List<Order_Product_Integration__c>();
List<Order> existingOrderList = new List<Order>();
Map<String,Order> orderMap = new Map<String,Order>();
Map<String,String> productMap = new Map<String,String>();
Set<String> priceBookSet =  new Set<String>();
List<PriceBookEntry> pricebookEntryList = new List<PriceBookEntry>();
Map<String, PriceBookEntry> priceBookEntryMap = new Map<String, PriceBookEntry>();
boolean hasErrors = false;
Map<String, Integer> errorMap = new Map<String, Integer>();
String error,productCode,uniqueProductEntry = '';
 
  try{
    //Querying on Order Level starts
    existingOrderList = [SELECT id,Name,Line_Number__c,CurrencyIsoCode,Pricebook2Id from order LIMIT 50000];
    if(existingOrderList.size()>0){
        for(order ord:existingOrderList){
            string LineAndName =ord.Line_Number__c+''+ord.Name;
            orderMap.put(LineAndName.toLowerCase(),ord);
            priceBookSet.add(ord.Pricebook2Id);
        } 
    }
    //end
     //Query to get price book entry id Logic starts
    for(Order_Product_Integration__c ordIntProd : scope){             
        string LineAndNameProduct = ordIntProd.Line_Number__c+''+ordIntProd.JDE_Order_Number__c;
        if(ordIntProd.Item_Number_Short__c!=null){
            productMap.put(LineAndNameProduct,ordIntProd.Item_Number_Short__c); 
        }else if(ordIntProd.X2nd_Item_Number__c!=null){
            productMap.put(LineAndNameProduct,ordIntProd.X2nd_Item_Number__c); 
        }else if(ordIntProd.X3rd_Item_Number__c!=null){
            productMap.put(LineAndNameProduct,ordIntProd.X3rd_Item_Number__c); 
        }
    }
    //END
    //Querying Pricebook entry List
    pricebookEntryList =[Select Id, CurrencyIsoCode,Name,Product2.productcode,UnitPrice, PriceBook2Id, PriceBook2.Name From PriceBookEntry
                         WHERE PriceBook2Id IN:priceBookSet 
                         AND Product2.productcode IN:productMap.values()
                         AND IsActive=TRUE];
   
    if(!pricebookEntryList.isempty()){
        String uniqueCode = '';
        for(PriceBookEntry priceEntry : pricebookEntryList) {
            uniqueCode = priceEntry.Pricebook2Id + priceEntry.CurrencyIsoCode + priceEntry.Product2.productcode;
            priceBookEntryMap.put(uniqueCode,priceEntry);
        }
    }
    //end
      //Iterating over product Integration
    for(Order_Product_Integration__c ordProdIntegration : scope){
         productCode = '';
         string LineandJDENum = ordProdIntegration.Line_Number__c+''+ordProdIntegration.JDE_Order_Number__c;
            string productLineMap = LineandJDENum.toLowerCase();
     orderItem ordPrd = new orderItem();
        ordPrd.ExternalId__c=string.valueof(productLineMap);
        ordPrd.quantity=decimal.valueof(ordProdIntegration.Units_Secondary_Quantity_Ordered__c);
        if(ordProdIntegration.Item_Number_Short__c!=null){
            productCode = ordProdIntegration.Item_Number_Short__c;
        }else if(ordProdIntegration.X2nd_Item_Number__c!=null){
            productCode = ordProdIntegration.X2nd_Item_Number__c;
        }else if(ordProdIntegration.X3rd_Item_Number__c!=null){
            productCode = ordProdIntegration.X3rd_Item_Number__c;
        }
        //debug block - remove==========================
        system.debug('@@@@@productCode158@@@@@@@'+productCode);
        system.debug('ordermap####################'+orderMap);
        system.debug('orderproductiNTEGRATION@@@'+ordProdIntegration.Id);
        system.debug('ordproductiNTEGRATION details@@@'+ordProdIntegration);
        system.debug('ordPrd.PricebookEntryId#######'+ordPrd.PricebookEntryId);
        system.debug('productLineMap@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'+productLineMap);
        system.debug('priceBookSet@@@@@@@'+priceBookSet);
        system.debug('orderMap@@@@@@@'+orderMap);
        system.debug('product NUMBS()@@@@@@'+productMap.values());
        system.debug('pricebookEntryList.values()@@@@@@'+pricebookEntryList);
        system.debug('pricebookEntryList keyset@@@@'+pricebookEntryMap.keyset());
        system.debug('pricebookEntryList values@@@@'+pricebookEntryMap.values());
        //end===========================================================
       
        if(!orderMap.isempty () && orderMap.containskey(productLineMap)){
            if(orderMap.get(productLineMap).CurrencyIsoCode == ordProdIntegration.CurrencyIsoCode &&  ordProdIntegration.CurrencyIsoCode =='GBP'){
                  ordPrd.UnitPrice = ordProdIntegration.Amount_Price_per_Unit__c;
               }
              else if(orderMap.get(productLineMap).CurrencyIsoCode == ordProdIntegration.CurrencyIsoCode && ordProdIntegration.CurrencyIsoCode =='EUR'){
                           ordPrd.UnitPrice = ordProdIntegration.Amount_Foreign_Price_per_Unit__c;
              }
          
            if(orderMap.get(productLineMap).CurrencyIsoCode == ordProdIntegration.CurrencyIsoCode){
                  ordPrd.orderId =orderMap.get(productLineMap).Id;
                
            }
           uniqueProductEntry = orderMap.get(productLineMap).pricebook2Id + orderMap.get(productLineMap).CurrencyIsoCode + productCode;
          }
        
        system.debug('@@uniqueProductEntry@@@'+uniqueProductEntry);
       if(!pricebookEntryMap.isempty() && pricebookEntryMap.containskey(uniqueProductEntry)
          && pricebookEntryMap.get(uniqueProductEntry).CurrencyIsoCode ==ordProdIntegration.CurrencyIsoCode ){
             ordPrd.PricebookEntryId =pricebookEntryMap.get(uniqueProductEntry).Id;       /*pricebookEntryMap.get(uniqueProductEntry).Id;*/
              ordPrd.ListPrice= pricebookEntryMap.get(uniqueProductEntry).UnitPrice;
              uniqueProductEntry ='';
        }
        
        system.debug('ordPrd.orderId*******'+ordPrd.orderId+'@@@@@@prdId@@@@@'+ordProdIntegration.Id);
        system.debug('ord **********'+ordPrd);
        ordPrd.product2Id='01t3H000000PVTm'; //hardcoded for Testing Purpose
        createProductList.add(ordPrd);
    }
      system.debug('createProductList@@@@'+createProductList);
      system.debug('createProductList@@@@'+createProductList.size());
       
      if(!createProductList.isempty()) {
          Database.upsertResult[] lsr = Database.upsert(createProductList,OrderItem.fields.ExternalId__c,false);
          Integer recordid = 0;
          error = '';
          integer count = 0;
          for (Database.upsertResult res : lsr) {
              if (res.isSuccess()) {
                  orderProduct.add(res.getId());
              }else{
                  hasErrors = true;
                  for(Database.Error err : res.getErrors()){
                      //error+='Record ID: ' + res.getId() + ' - ';
                      error+= err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage();
                      error+= 'Fields: '+err.getFields();
                      error+='\n';
                      if(err.getStatusCode() == system.StatusCode.REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING){
                          if(errorMap.containsKey(err.getMessage())){
                              count = errorMap.get(err.getMessage());
                              errorMap.put(err.getMessage(),++count);
                          }else{
                              errorMap.put(err.getMessage(),1);
                          }
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }
    //handling error
    if(hasErrors){
        OrderExceptionLogController ordExcept = new OrderExceptionLogController('CT1_BatchOrderLineUpdate','Execute()',error,errorMap,
                                                                                System.Now(),Id.valueOf(UserInfo.getUserId())); 
        OrderExceptionLogController.createLog(ordExcept);
    }
    
    system.debug('orderProduct@@@@'+orderProduct);
    
    if(!orderProduct.isempty()){
        for(orderItem ordProd : [SELECT Id,Line_Number__c,order.name from orderItem where Id IN:orderProduct]){
            string concatOrdAndLine = ordProd.Line_Number__c+''+ordProd.order.name;
            orderAndLines.add(concatOrdAndLine);
        }      
    }
    system.debug('orderAndLines@@@@'+orderAndLines);
    if(!orderAndLines.isempty()){
        for(Order_Product_Integration__c ordProduct:scope){
            string concatOrdAndLine = ordProduct.Line_Number__c+''+ordProduct.JDE_Order_Number__c;
            if(orderAndLines.contains(concatOrdAndLine)){
                ordProduct.Status__c =ORDERINTEGRATION_SUCESSSTATUS;
                ordProduct.Job_Status__c=ORDERINTEGRATION_JOBSTATUS ;
                ordProduct.Status_Description__c = ORDERINTEGRATION_CREATED;
            }else{
                ordProduct.Status__c =ORDERINTEGRATION_ERROR ;
                ordProduct.Status_Description__c = ORDERINTEGRATION_ERRORSTATUS;
            }
            updateOrderIntegration.add(ordProduct);
        }
    }
    system.debug('updateOrderIntegration@@@'+updateOrderIntegration);
    if (updateOrderIntegration.size() > 0) {
        Database.SaveResult[] orderIntegration = Database.update(updateOrderIntegration,false);
    }
}

catch(exception ex){
     OrderExceptionLogController ordExcept = new OrderExceptionLogController('CT1_BatchOrderLineUpdate','Execute()',ex.getMessage(),null,
                                                                            System.Now(),Id.valueOf(UserInfo.getUserId())); 
    OrderExceptionLogController.createLog(ordExcept);
}


 }
 global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
//OrderLine
}
```

For same batch class in START Method, if I use particular record for example:
WHERE  id='8013H000000Ec7rQAC'. It works fine. If I try with multiple records, itsnot working.

### **Edit**

**Worked**

commented below Line of code:

```
    // if(orderMap.get(productLineMap).CurrencyIsoCode == 
    ordProdIntegration.CurrencyIsoCode){
                // ordPrd.orderId =orderMap.get(productLineMap).Id;
                //}
```

added below Line

```
     ordprd.order = new order(External_Id__c=productLineMap);
```

I would like to know answer for below 2 questions:

```
  1.  ordprd.order = new order(External_Id__c=productLineMap);
```

above Line of code works fine. If externalId isnt present it shows below error

> INVALID_FIELD: Foreign key external ID: 24203223 not found for field External_Id__c in entity OrderFields: ()

**How can I avoid this error. ? Any way to block that error?**

2. Tried with database.insert but still itsnot working. Leave about external Id,i have passed order Id based on it should create order product. thats also not happening

   ```
    database.insert(createProductList,false);
   ```

why its so??

Answer (score 2):

The error and the debug log show you what data is missing. All records past the first are missing the `OrderId` relationship field:

> 16:12:40.0 (49008899)|USER_DEBUG|[187]|DEBUG|createProductList@@@@(OrderItem: {ExternalId__c=24187329,Quantity=24, UnitPrice=210.0, OrderId=8013H000000EbuyQAC, PricebookEntryId=01u3H000001kceQQAQ}, OrderItem:{ExternalId__c=24203223,Quantity=1, UnitPrice=507.0, PricebookEntryId=01u3H000001kceQQAQ}, OrderItem:{ExternalId__c=24219687,Quantity=24,UnitPrice=507.0, PricebookEntryId=01u3H000001kceQQAQ})

This seems to also explain why your class works with lists of size one - it is populating that field only on the first created record.

### Edit

The most likely reason that all records are failing to insert is that the corresponding External Ids of records without `OrderId` populated do not exist, so that the upsert is resolved to an insert.